# multiple pdfs showing in browser 1 by 1

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, iframe

I have page where i'll be showing the list of files uploaded by a user (pdf files).
Now, what i want to achieve is show those pdf files 1 at a time below this list table.

1st part i am able to do...where i'll call my controller method and fetch the list, then i'll populate the table in my jsp page.
2nd part i am not sure, as in how should i approach it?

1st method that returns the list:

```
@RequestMapping("/tasks/viewDocuments.do")
public ModelAndView viewDocuments(@RequestParam("reqId") Integer reqId) {
    try{
        log.info("inside viewDocuments, reqId: "+reqId);

        //get the file details and show the list on page. 

        return new ModelAndView("tasks/viewDocumentsHTML" , "wrapper" ,"" );
    }catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("error in viewDocuments: "+e);
        return new ModelAndView ("xstream", "response","system.error");
    }
}
```

2nd method that returns pdf:

```
@RequestMapping("/tasks/showDocumentsInIframe.do")
public void showDocumentsInIframe(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try{
        log.info("inside showDocumentsInIframe");
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        String fileURL = "http://www.saronicferries.gr/content/pdfFiles/sample.pdf";
        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        log.debug("length: "+connection.getContentLength());
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(out);

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        response.setContentLength(connection.getContentLength());
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=help.pdf");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "cache, must-revalidate");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

        while ((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        log.info("finishing showDocumentsInIframe");
        bufferedOutputStream.flush();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("error in showDocumentsInIframe: "+e);
        //return new ModelAndView ("xstream", "response","system.error");
    }
}
```

jsp page:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sec"
    uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="/public/css/jquery.css"/>"></link>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="/public/css/portal_style.css"/>"></link>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/public/js/jquery/jquery-1.3.min.js"/>"></script>

<form>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1"
        style="display: inline;">
        <tr class="portlet-table-header">
            <td align="left">Sr. No.:</td>
            <td align="left">File Name:</td>
            <td align="left"></td>
            <td align="left"></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="workList" items="${wrapper.voList}">
            <tr class="portlet-table-body">
                <td>${workList.srNo}</td>
                <td>${workList.fileName}</td>
                <td><a href="javascript:taskDetails.viewDocuments()">View</a></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:taskDetails.removeDocuments()">Remove</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</form>
<br><br>
<embed id="pdfViewer" src="/tasks/showDocumentsInIframe.do" width="500" height="375" />
```

The call to the second method never works.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you saying the `showDocumentsInIframe()` call doesn't work?  Have you tried using some sort of network traffic analyzer (fiddler, firebug, chrome's dev tools) to see what is being sent from the browser and returned?

Comment: It doesnt work. and no i havent tested it with firebug. i have logging and the logs arent appearing in my log file for this operation.

Comment: Not being able to see your full code, walk through it, nor see logs I have to assume you mean that the method is running but not doing what you intend it to do.  I would suggest to look at the resulting response from the server using one of the suggested tools (or some other tool, like Wire Shark, if you like).  You could be getting a 400, in which case I would say that you have an issue where your client is not setting the Accepts header right.  You could be getting a 500 because something exploded.  You could be getting a 402: Not found.  There is no telling unless you look.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the inputs. I'll check using firebug.

Comment: So, again, things to look for: HTTP Response Code and response payload (am I getting a 200 OK or some other response code I wasn't expecting, am I getting HTML/JSON/XML instead of the expected PDF).  For return codes take a look at the W3C's page:  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: @CodeChimp i am getting a 404 error (for src="/tasks/showDocumentsInIframe.do").

Comment: Ok. so, its working now after i did few small tweaks. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since a 404 is a "Not Found" error, I am guessing you either modified the `@RequestMapping` or the URL you were sending on the client side.  This is a good example where basic troubleshooting can take you quite far.  Sadly, it doesn't seem like many people were taught this in their studies.

Comment: @CodeChimp It works only in case of Firefox. The document fails to open in Chrome and IE. For IE it says "the documents doesnt start with '%PDF'". and for Chrome it says "Failed to Load PDF Document".

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with the PDF file.  Can you try saving what you are getting from the web server to a file and opening it in something like Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: @CodeChimp The same document opens properly with Firefox. So, i dont think there is any issue with the document. However, http://www.saronicferries.gr/content/pdfFiles/sample.pdf is the document.

Comment: You cannot assume that Firefox opening the PDF means that other browsers can/will.  The newer versions of FF include built-in PDF readers, as does Chrome I believe.  This means they are opening/reading the file using different code.  It would be the same as trying to argue that a website looks fine in Safari but fails in IE6.  Different rendering engines means there is a possibility for different results.  The error message you are getting seems to correlate with this theory.

Comment: @CodeChimp Just found out that the URL from where i was reading the document isnt opening. So, i'll try with another URL.